# Syncing offline data sequentially whenever internet is available

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm working on a project that collects user data and stores in a offline SQLite database later starts syncing whenever internet connection is available.

From my SQLlite database I'm syncing those entry one by one with the status "PENDING"
[image]

I made some working codes but these are not efficient and I'm facing these problems.

**1 - My BroadcastReceiver activates only when the network status changes but it doesn't work when the phone is already connected to the internet. I want to start syncing data whenever the internet is available not only after chaning the internet status**

**2 - I'm using a simple loop which starts from the first index of a row with the status "PENDING" and runs till it reaches the total number of pending items. I want a efficient way to do that.**

I used those two functions inside **DatabaseHandler** class,

Function #1 `pendingContactCounter()` which counts the number of contacts with the status "PENDING".
For example if we consider the uploaded table image the function will return 2 as two contact are availble with the status "PENDING"

Function #2 `pendingContactID()` returns the ID of first row with the status "PENDING"
From the above image it will return 2 as ID 2 has the status "PENDING"

For internet connection detection I made this BroadcastReceiver

```
 public class InternetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            ConnectivityManager cm = ((ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
            if (cm == null)
                return;
            if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                // CONNECTED
                Log.d("CONNECTION STATUS", "CONNECTED!");

               Intent service_intent = new Intent(context, uploadService.class);
            context.startService(service_intent);
            }

            } else {
                // NOT CONNECTED
                Log.d("CONNECTION STATUS", "NOT CONNECTED!");
            }
        }
```

And a service that updates the "PENDING" entries to "SENT"

```
public class uploadService extends IntentService {

    private int total_request;
    private int pending_id;

    public uploadService() {
        super("uploadService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        total_request = db.pendingContactCounter();
        pending_id = db.pendingContactID();

        Log.d("TOTAL REQUEST: ", "" + total_request);
        Log.d("PENDING ID: ", "" + pending_id);

        for (int i = pending_id; i <= total_request + 1; i++) {

            db.updateData(i, "SENT");
        }

    }
}
```

Finally the manifest looks like this,

```
<receiver android:name=".connectionReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="uploadService" >
        </service>
```

Comment: If data is submitted by user off line, after submission you can check if there is network it will start data uploading service. Otherwise keeps in local DB. For checking Internet connection you can use alarm manager with specified time interval to check network status.It will check network if available start data uploading.

Comment: Have you got any answer to your question?